# Proving the sequence $(-1)^n$ is divergent by the formal definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that the definition of a convergence sequence definition is:

$$(\exists L\in \mathbb{R})(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})[n \ge N \Rightarrow |x_n-L| < \varepsilon]$$

And by using the negation, we can obtain the divergence sequence definition:

($\forall$ L $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$)($\exists$ $\epsilon$ > 0)($\forall$ N $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$)($\exists$ n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$)[n $\ge$ N and |$x_n-L|$ $\ge$ $\epsilon$]

So, as far as I understand, for any real number "L" I can find an epsilon such that for any natural number, the following holds true: |$x_n-L|$ < $\epsilon$

Since we have $a_n=(-1)^{n}$, the sequence alternates between 1 and -1.
If we say L = 1 (From the definition the inequality is valid $\forall$ L $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$).
Then we have: |$x_n-1|$ $\ge$ $\epsilon$, but as the sequence is 1 or -1, if we plug 1:

|1-1| $\ge$ $\epsilon$ => $0$ $\ge$ $\epsilon$ > $0$, which is not valid because from the definition $\epsilon$ > $0$. What am I doing or understanding wrong?

Comment: If $0<\epsilon <1$ and you think perhaps $L=1$ then rather than "plug $1$" instead try $x_n=-1$

Comment: For any sequence $x_n$, if it is convergent to some $x$, then $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon\forall n\geq N$. So, if the sequence is not convergent, you should find **at least one** $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $|x_n-x|\geq\epsilon_0\forall n\geq N$. So your question has now reduced to find one such $\epsilon$. Can you do it from here?

Comment: Yes, I got the idea, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your definition of divergence, you only need to prove that there exists SOME $n$ larger than $N$ for which $\mid a_n - L \mid > \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a positive number of choice. To prove this sequence diverges, we can select $\epsilon = 0.5$.

If you want to prove the series does not converge to $L=1$, you only need to select an odd $n$ larger than $N$. Then, $a_n = -1$ and its difference from $L$ exceeds $\epsilon$(This is of course not true for ALL $n\geq N$).

To prove the series does not converge for any choice of $L$, again you can choose $\epsilon = 0.5$. This would imply that for any $N$, all $a_n$'s where $n \geq N$ have the property that $\mid a_n - L \mid < 0.5$. But that would imply:

$$ \mid 1 - L \mid < 0.5 $$

$$ \mid -1 - L \mid < 0.5 $$

This is impossible as no real number satisfies the two said inequalities simultaneously. Therefore, this sequence does not converge.

Comment: But from the definition, when it is said (∀ N ∈ ℕ)(∃ n ∈ ℕ)n ≥ N, doesn't it mean that it must follow for all natural numbers? I mean, for all N we can find "n", which is always true since the set of the naturals says that if "n" belongs to it, "n+1" belongs to the set as well?

Comment: I would have said it this way.

For any real number, $L$, there exists a real number, $\epsilon$, 
such that for any natural number, $N$, I can find an $n > N$ such that $|x_n−L| > ϵ$

Comment: Wait, I think I got it. For any natural number I can find AT LEAST one n >N, such that the inequality with epsilon will hold true?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

When verifying a quantified definition like that of a divergent sequence, you should treat variables following "for all" as being given to you - you have no say in how they are chosen. Variables following "there exists" may be chosen by you using any previously established variables.

Read the definition of divergent sequence left-to-right:

1. for every $L \in \mathbf R$:  a value of $L$ is given to you. You don't know anything else about it.
2. there exists $\epsilon > 0$: we get to pick this one. How about $\epsilon = 1$.
3. for every $N \in \mathbf N$: again this is given to you. You don't get to define it.
4. there exists $n \in \mathbf N$: we get to pick this one too. Its value can depend on $L$, $\epsilon$, and $N$ if necessary. How about $n = 2N$ if $L < 0$ and $n = 2N+1$ if $L \ge 0$.

Then:

- $|(-1)^n - L| = |1-L| > 1$ if $L < 0$, and
- $|(-1)^n - L| = |(-1) - L| \ge 1$ if $L \ge 0$.

In both cases you have $n \ge N$ and $|(-1)^n - L| \ge \epsilon$. This verifies the definition.